# Tangent planes of a surface parallel to a fixed direction

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm learning differential geometry, specifically the theory of surfaces, and need help with the following problem:

> Consider the surface $S$ given by $x_1 = x_2 - f(x_2 - x_3)$, where $f \in C^2$.
>
> Show that every tangent plane of $S$ are parallel to a fixed direction.

Here's my work so far:

We first need to find the parametric representation of $S$. Setting $x_2 = u$ and $x_3 = v$ give $x_1 = u - f(u - v)$. Therefore, the parametric representation of $S$ is given by

$$S : \vec x(u, v) = (u - f(u - v)) \vec e_1 + u \vec e_2 + v \vec e_3$$

or in a more conviennent/compact notation

$$S : \vec x(u, v) = (u - f, u ,v).$$

The equation of the tangent plane at $\vec x(u_P, v_P)$ in parametric form with parameters $\mu, \lambda$ is given by

$$\vec T_P(S) : \vec y = \vec x(u_P, v_P) + \lambda \vec x_u(u_P, v_P) + \mu \vec x_v(u_P, v_P) \tag{*}$$

where

$$\vec x_u(u_P, v_P) = (1 - f', 1, 0)$$

and

$$\vec x_v(u_P, v_P) = (f', 0, 1).$$

Substituting in $(*)$ yields

$$\vec T_P(S) : \vec y = (u - f, u ,v) + \lambda (1 - f', 1, 0) + \mu (f', 0, 1). \tag{**}$$

---

From $(**)$ I don't know how to prove that the tangent planes are parallel to a fixed direction. I'm also confused by the meaning of the phrase "parallel to a fixed direction". Does this means that the tangent planes of the surface are all parallel to some plane of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: $f$ is a function of a single variable (call it t). $f_u$ and $f_v$ do not make sense.

Comment: At any rate, you need to use the chain rule and your $\vec x_v$ has a sign error. Once you fix that, you should be able to show that every tangent plane is parallel to the vector $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for pointing out my error. Using the chain rule, the first component of $\vec x_v$ should be $f'$ (instead of $-f'$ that I previously had). I corrected my post accordingly and removed the $f_u, f_v$ symbols. It is still unclear to me how I should continue from here. Do I need to combine the vectors components together and substitute appropriate values for $\lambda, \mu$?

Comment: Yes, by inspection you can see how to choose $\lambda$ and $\mu$ to eliminate the $f'$ and get a constant vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given
$$
x_{\,1}  = x_{\,2}  + f(x_{\,2}  - x_{\,3} )\quad i.e.\quad F(x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} ) = 0
$$
we can rewrite it ,as
$$
x_{\,1}  - x_{\,3}  = x_{\,2}  - x_{\,3}  + f(x_{\,2}  - x_{\,3} )\quad  \Rightarrow \quad y_{\,1}  = y_{\,2}  + f(y_{\,2} )\quad i.e.\quad G(y_{\,1} ,y_{\,2} ) = 0
$$
or, otherwise, as
$$
x_{\,1}  - x_{\,2}  = f(x_{\,2}  - x_{\,3} )\quad  \Rightarrow \quad z_{\,1}  = f(z_{\,2} )\quad i.e.\quad H(z_{\,1} ,z_{\,2} ) = 0
$$
Now, the tranformations
$$
\left( {x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} } \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( {y_{\,1} ,y_{\,2} ,y_{\,3} } \right)\quad \left( {x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} } \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( {z_{\,1} ,z_{\,2} ,z_{\,3} } \right)
$$
with the understanding that $y_3$ and $z_3$ are vectors independent from other two, so as to complete the respective basis,
are linear transformations, by which planes transform into planes, and "tangent to $F$" into "tangent to $G$" / "tangent to $H$".
$G$ and $H$ are clearly cylinders, with axes $y_3$ and $z_3$ respectively, so their tangent planes will all be parallel to those directions.
In the Euclidean space such a direction would be unique, that of $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although your method is a lot quicker than mine I do not understand it unfortunately. In the second step you subtracted $x_3$ on both sides of the original equation of the surface but after that I don't understand what you are doing. Would you mind explaining what is the general method you are using with words?

Comment: @VonKar, well, sorry, my answer was very concise: I expanded it a bit further and hope it is clear now.